# Failing to execute a tkinter python gui app from php web application

Tags: php, python

I'm able to execute simple python scripts from php but trying to execute a python script that pops up a tkinter gui fails.The gui is able to pop up when I use the console (terminal) but fails from php's shell_exec command. **I need help on how to do it.** **I have read through many existing questions and solutions but can't find any related to my situation.** Sample code is as follows:

```
$python = (shell_exec("/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3 /path/t/my/python/gui.py")); //This is on mac

if ($python) {
        $message = "Successful!";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
        $URL = "http://localhost/my-localhost/myphppage.php";

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href = '{$URL}';</script>";
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="0;URL=' . $URL . '">'; 
    }
```

My python script has the #!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3

Comment: you can't run tkinter programs from a webserver. You might be able to under certain circumstances, but as a user you would never see it -- it would run on the server's display.

Comment: thank you Bryan for enlightening me on this. What would be your workaround advise on it? What caused me to try and run tkinter gui from php was the failure of my long running python script to execute from php even after changing the maximum_execution_time to 720 seconds because the average response time when I run the script from command line was 2 minutes. So I thought if I cause it to pop up a gui it would keep running in the background.

Comment: That's a completely different question. If your real need is to run a long running process in the background of a webserver, you should be asking how to do that.

Comment: For sure Bryan, that's my real problem and what I read on fora did not solve my problem so I thought if I tried popping up a gui would solve the problem, but to no avail.